# Quartx SimpleTrigger going to BLOCKED state after few repeat intervals

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using SimpleTrigger to schedule a job which is supposed to run indefinitely (repeat count -1).

And i am using JDBC store to persist the job state in DB.

But the trigger is firing for some intervals (in my case always 8) and goes to BLOCKED state. TO be specific, the value of TRIGGERS_STATE will be changed to BLOCKED in QRTZ_TRIGGERS table. Note my prefix for Quartx tables is QRTZ_
Below are my Job Trigger info.

repeat count: -1,
repeat Interval: 6 seconds,
start delay: 10 seconds

**MY quartz configurations:**

```
#===============================================================
#Configure ThreadPool
#===============================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
#===============================================================
#Configure JobStore
#===============================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime=20
# Flag to turn off to ignore all misfires
scheduler.ignoreMisfire=no

# Configuring JDBCJobStore with the Table Prefix
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

# Using DriverDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
```

Scheduler Class:

```
public static void scheduleJob(Class<? extends Job> job,JobDataMap dataMap) 
{

    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    try
    {
        JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(job)
                .withIdentity(job.getSimpleName()+"_"+DateUtil.getSystemDate(), job.getSimpleName() + "_group")
                .storeDurably()
                .usingJobData(dataMap)
                .requestRecovery()
                .build();

        SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(job.getSimpleName() + "_trigger_"+DateUtil.getSystemDateWithMs(), job.getSimpleName() + "_trigger_group")
                .startNow()                 
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().repeatSecondlyForever(10).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

        //logger.debug(scheduler.getMetaData().toString());
        scheduler.start();
    }
    catch (SchedulerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new SchedulerException("", e);
    }
}
```

Job Class:

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class MyJob  Implements Job
{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        getBeansFromContext(context);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); // Hibernate Session Factory
        // to do some DB opetations
    }

    private void getBeansFromContext(JobExecutionContext context) throws SchedulerException
    {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext)context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
        this.sessionFactory=applicationContext.getBean(SessionFactory.class);
    }
}
```

Spring bean configration for Quartz scheduler factory.

```
<beans:bean id="schedulerFactoryBean"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="jobFactory">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory"></beans:bean>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
<beans:property name="configLocation"
    value="resources/scheduler/Scheduler.properties" />
<beans:property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey"
    value="applicationContext" />
<beans:property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="taskExecutor"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"
p:corePoolSize="5" p:maxPoolSize="10" p:queueCapacity="100"
p:waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown="true" />
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the Job class you are executing?

Comment: Can be a problem related to transactions in your job. 
 
"Triggers go into the BLOCKED state when the job relating to them is executing and that job class is either a StatefulJob or has the @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation on it. Triggers leave the BLOCKED state when the executing stateful job completes." 

Source at: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/6739.page

Comment: FYI.. Identified that my jobs are struck in BLOCKED state because i had org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation on my job definition. After removing the DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation, jobs are now struck in ACQUIRED state for ever.

Comment: Edited the main post with my scheduler & job class, FYI

Comment: Have you tried to remove @PersistJobDataAfterExecution annotation also?

Comment: Yes. i tried that too. No luck :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38478/discussion-between-zerologiko-and-devp)

Comment: Thanks a lot Zerologiko. Looks like i identified the what is the problem & could resolve the issue. Will post more info on that soon.

Comment: Good! If my comment was useful to identify the problem, vote it up, it's better than thaks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally understood the problem and able to resolve it.

As @zerologiko commented the issue is with transaction. 
I am using Spring managed transaction with hibernate. Once i declare my transaction policy, Spring takes care of start/end of transactions.

Reason for the issue in my case:
Spring bean life cycle is not effective in the Scheduler Job. To elaborate on this,
as given in main post i had to even accessing applicationContext inside my job class using

> jobContext.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");

I am trying to update DB back with some status into one of our transaction database after the job is done.

I missed to realize initially that even the transaction are also controlled by Spring.
When those db updates were triggered from a job class, the transactions declared on my business methods had no effect.

According to my understanding, the trigger were going to Acquired as the threads which completed the job is not able to come back to pool.

To fix this problem, i manually opened/closed the transactions in my job class without relying on Spring CMT and it worked without issues.

Hope this helps someone who is facing same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issue with CRON trigger and the root cause is also due to the Spring managed transactions.

However, what I have done to fix the problem is a bit different than yours.

I have retained the @Transactional annotation at code level and instead configured an dedicated dataSource for Quartz to use for its own DB operations without intervention by Spring.

```
 <!-- Datasource used by Quartz -->
<bean id="quartzDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" ref="dbPassword"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${db.conn.pool.maxActive:30}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${db.conn.pool.maxIdle:15}"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="${db.conn.pool.minIdle:0}"/>
</bean>
<!-- Datasource used by Quartz --> 


 <!-- Assign an dedicated dataSource to quartz scheduler-->
 <bean id="cronJobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/quartz/quartz.properties"/>
    <property name="jobFactory" ref="springBeanJobFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="quartzDataSource"/>
 </bean>
```